# How do I create a custom mvc html helper for use in an editort emplate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I have an editor template for displaying a model's values in an html form for editing. In the editor template, I'm using a custom mvc html helper that displays/renders a checkbox. I noticed that when I would submit the form, the value of the checkbox wasn't being sent along with the rest of the model data. Upon inspecting the generated HTML, I noticed that the built-in html helpers that I used all had a name attribute who's value was prepended by an index value, i.e.

```
<input name="[0].CompanyName" type="text" value="CompanyName1">
<input name="[1].CompanyName" type="text" value="CompanyName2">
<input name="[2].CompanyName" type="text" value="CompanyName3">
```

but my custom html helper (checkbox) was rendered without the index value, i.e.

```
<input checked="checked" class="yesNoChk" id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" value="Y">
```

Hence why the value was not being passed back to my HttpPost controller method. Duh! There's no way to know that the custom checkbox belongs to any of the models.

So, my question is, how do I build a custom mvc html helper that is aware of the html element indexing assigned when an editor template is used? Microsoft obviously figured it out because all of the built-in html helpers work; my custom one doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the code of the HtmlHelper? ILSPY is very helpful with that!

Comment: FYI, ASP.NET MVC is open source at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/